# Angular2: How to make several GET requests at once

Tags: ajax, http, angular, promise

With a promise JS library (https://github.com/stackp/promisejs) I can make this:

```
promise.join([
    promise.get('/settings'),
    promise.get('/translations'),
    promise.get('/main-data')
]).then(function(results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```

Now I need to do this with Angular2. So I made a service with methods `getSettings`, `getTranslations`, etc. - but how do I `join` them in the component that uses this service ?

(And join them in such way that when and only when **all** requests finish - I'll run a functionality that uses all the responses?)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `forkJoin` operator for this

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';



//...some code

 Observable.forkJoin( 
    this.http.get('/settings').map((res:Response) => res.json()),
    this.http.get('/translations').map((res:Response) => res.json())
  )
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data[0], data[1]);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer didn't solved the problem, mostly because I didn't understand how to get the data `in` the component. But it still guided me very well :)

So, here is the final code:

```
// Service - "AppService.ts":
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

export class AppService {

    getAllData() {
        return Observable
            .forkJoin(
                this._http.get('/settings').map(res => res.json()),
                this._http.get('/translations').map(res => res.json())
            )
    }

}

// Component - "AppComponent.ts":
import {AppService} from './app.service';

export class AppComponent {

    AllData = {};

    appService
        .getAllData()
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                console.log('Responses from AJAX:');
                console.log(data);
                this.AllData = JSON.stringify(data)
            },
            error => alert(error)
        );

}
```